# Kafka Connect schema format for JSONConverter

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka Connect to retrieve an existing schema from the schema registry and then trying to convert the returned schema string using JSONConverter (org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JSONConverter).

Unfortunately, I get an error from JSONConverter:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Unknown schema type: object
```

I viewed the JSONConverter code and the error occurs because the schema "type" returned from the schema registry is "object" (see below) but JSONConverter does not recognize that type.

Questions:

1. Is the retrieved schema usable for JSONConverter? If yes, am I using this incorrectly?
2. Is JSONConverter expecting a different format?  If yes, does someone know what the format JSONConverter is expecting?
3. Is there a different method of concerting the schema registry response into a "Schema"?

Here are the relevant artifacts:

schema registry response (when querying for a particular schema):

```
[{"subject":"test-schema","version":1,"id":1,"schemaType":"JSON","schema":"{\"title\":\"test-schema\",\"type\":\"object\",\"required\":[\"id\"],\"additionalProperties\":false,\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}}"}]
```

When the text above is cleaned up a bit, the relevant schema component ("schema") is shown below:

```
{
  "title":"test-schema",
  "type":"object",
  "required":["id"],
  "additionalProperties":false,
  "properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"}}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JSONConverter` doesn't actually use "JSONSchema" specification. It has its own (not well documented) format. It also doesn't integrate at all with the Schema Registry.

An object is `struct` type. - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas

If you intend on using actual JSONSchema (and the registry), you need to use the Converter from Confluent - `io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter`

> Is there a different method of concerting the schema registry response into a "Schema"

If you use the Schema Registry Java Client, then yes, use the `getSchemaById` method, then the `schemaType()` and `rawSchema()` method of that response should get you close to what you want. With that, you would pass it to some JSONSchema library (e.g. `org.everit.json.schema`, which is used by the registry)